# jQuery FormCache prevent variable post

Tags: jquery, html, post

I have used this [tutorial](http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/jquery-plugin-for-caching-forms-using-html5-local-storage/). It is working, stores all the data, but it prevent form to post varaibles to another file. This other file do not get the variables so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is from a hungarian programming forum. Special thanks for this code to ValakiMás(a member of that forum)!

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.FormCache = function( options ) {

        if(typeof(Storage)==="undefined"){
                alert('local storage is not available');
        }

    var settings = $.extend({
    }, options );

    function on_submit() {
      var form = $(this);
      var key = form.attr('name');                            
      form.find('input, select').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
        if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
          data[input.attr('name')] = input.is(':checked');
        }else {
          data[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
        }
        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(data);
      });
    };

    return this.each(function() {
      var element = $(this).submit(on_submit);
      var key = element.attr('name');
      var data = false;

      if(localStorage[key]) {
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
      }

      if(!data) {
        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify({});
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
      }

      element.find('input, select').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('type') != 'submit') {
            var input = $(this);
            var value = data[input.attr('name')];
            if(input.attr('type') == 'radio' || input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
              if(value) {
                input.attr('checked', true);         
            } else {
                input.removeAttr('checked');
              }
            } else {
              input.val(value);
            }
        }
      });
 });

 };
}( jQuery ))
```

It is working perfectly!